# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use'). I Defined the app

Tags: javascript

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')
    at <anonymous> (e:\Responsive_WebPage\server\index.js:22:4)
    at run (internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    --- await ---
    at runMainESM (internal/modules/run_main:105:21)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:138:5)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:28:49)
```

this is the code :

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import multer from "multer";
import helmet from "helmet";
import morgan from "morgan";
import path from "path";  
import { fileURLToPath } from "url"; 

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json()).
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({policy:"cross-origin"}));
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "30mb", extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit:"30mb", extended:true}));
app.use(cors()) //Cross Orign Resource Policies. 
app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/assets')));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: For some reason, `const app = express();` is assigning `undefined`. You need to figure out what's wrong with the `express()` function in `express.js`.

Comment: It's also possible that one of those `app.use()` calls makes `app` `undefined`. I suggest you comment out each of them and then uncomment one by one to see which one causes an issue.